# Cloning (mirroring) laptop display to area of external monitor display

Tags: nvidia, display, clone, twinview

I'm using Maverick "10.10" Meercat on a HP Pavilion tx2110.  This machine has an NVidia Go6150 graphics card, and sports a 1280x800 display.  I have an external monitor which can do 1280x1024 resolution.  FWIW I'm using openbox as my window manager; as I understand it this shouldn't be a factor.

I'd like to clone the display to the monitor, so that the size of the desktop remains at 1280x800, and there is a horizontal blank area on the external monitor.  I.E. I want to avoid having to pan the display of the desktop on either monitor.  So the actual resolution of the monitor would be 1280x1024, but the resolution of the section of the monitor where stuff was actually being displayed would be 1280x800.

Using the nvidia-settings applet, I'm able to set up the cloned display so that the desktop size is 1280x1024 (the resolution of the external monitor), but can't find a way to instead have the desktop size stay at the resolution of the laptop's built-in display.

Is this achievable?  Ideally I'd like the external monitor's blank area to be at the top of the screen, i.e. for it to align the display with the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Your monitor most likely does not support that resolution, if not the nVidia settings manager would have allowed you to use that resolution. Unfortunately you may not be able to achieve what you are looking for.

You could do it if there were some custom option available from the drivers, but neither the open-source nor proprietary drivers have this feature.

Comment: I'm quite sure the monitor doesn't support a 1280x800 resolution; I want to run it at 1280x1024 and just use part of the display.  I edited the question to hopefully make that a bit more clear.

Comment: you can't do that with the way how graphics currently work.

Comment: Is this due to limitations of xorg, or of the nvidia drivers?  I would probably be okay with sacrificing acceleration to have this work, if there's a workaround somehow that way.

Comment: a bit of both really. You could do it if there were some custom option in the drivers, but neither the open-source nor proprietary drivers have this feature.

Comment: Finally came back to this one — I guess we don't get updates on comments that don't use our @username.  If you edit the answer to include the comment info, especially your last comment, I'll accept this as the answer.  But I don't want someone to cruise through here without reading the comments and misunderstand the situation.